# How do I find the "chromium version" in a chromium based web browser?

Tags: chromium

For error reporting etc I would like to know the version of chromium used by a chromium based web browser. Can I find that somewhere in the users web browser?

Answer (score 2):

execute "navigator.userAgent" in javascript

it will return a string similar to

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
```

with Chromium as 3rd

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but is that for chromium based browsers? Or just for Google Chrome?

Comment: well I knnow it also works for Safari and firefox and certain inAppBrowsers (which were chromium based as well i think) Edge as well obviously cant vouch for selfmade browsers

Comment: Thanks, do you know where to find documentation for this?

Comment: on the internet :P 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

Comment: User agent for ``Chromium`` will be ``Chrome``, not ``Chromium``

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Thanks, but there is no info about what I am looking for.

Comment: @Asesh I believe that you mean that Chromium based browsers will contain "Chrome" in  `navigator.userAgent`? Do you have a link about that?

Comment: @Leo Chromium developer here. You could just download a Chromium fork and test it.

Comment: @Asesh Ok, thanks. But anyone could fork and change the string in `navigat.userAgent`. Do you say that there is a recommendation to keep "Chrome" in the string?

Comment: I meant you will see ``Chrome/version`` even if you are on Chromium. If you remove ``Chrome`` from the user agent then many sites won't be compatible with your Chromium fork.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions about using `navigator.userAgent`. They might be useful (not sure), but a more safe way seems to use something like

```
if (typeof chrome === "undefined") {
   // Not chromium based, probably Firefox then
}
```

Any comments on this? @Asesh?